# How can I use removeChild in cocos2d-html

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, undefined, removechild, cocos2d-js

How can I solve this `undefined` `gameLayer` error in this code?
It keep saying that `gameLayer` is not defined

```
var pause = setTimeout(function(){
    if(pickedTiles[0].pictureValue!=pickedTiles[1].pictureValue){
        pickedTiles[0].initWithFile("assets/cover.png");
        pickedTiles[1].initWithFile("assets/cover.png");
    }
    else{
        gameLayer.removeChild(pickedTiles[0]);
        gameLayer.removeChild(pickedTiles[1]);
    }
    pickedTiles = [];
}, 1000);}
```

this is the complete code
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfp6fudg31ojyfp/gameScript.js?dl=0

---

Solved, using

```
pickedTiles[0].removeFromParent();
pickedTiles[1].removeFromParent();
```

instead of

```
 gameLayer.removeChild(pickedTiles[0]);
 gameLayer.removeChild(pickedTiles[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check before if `gameLayer` exists:

```
var pause = setTimeout(function(){
    if(pickedTiles[0].pictureValue!=pickedTiles[1].pictureValue){
        pickedTiles[0].initWithFile("assets/cover.png");
        pickedTiles[1].initWithFile("assets/cover.png");
    }
    else{
        if(gameLayer){
            gameLayer.removeChild(pickedTiles[0]);
            gameLayer.removeChild(pickedTiles[1]);
        }
    }
    pickedTiles = [];
}, 1000);}
```